# Suppressing 'Bibliography' title

Tags: bibliographies

In attempting to solve my earlier problem I found that I ended my first chapter with

```
\section{References}
\bibliographystyle{naturemag}
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}
\bibliography{introrefs}
```

Which resulted in ensuing chapters and sections having problems with titles and numbering. So I deleted the \renewcommand to have, instead:

```
\section{References}
\bibliographystyle{naturemag}
\bibliography{introrefs}
```

This solved my problem with missing section titles and deleted first letter. But now I have:

'1.5 References\
Bibliography\
[1] Reference 1\
[2] Reference 2\
[3] etc...'\

**How can I suppress the 'Bibliography'?**

Comment: eek `\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}` redefining section is brave but defining it to have a different number of arguments is even braver. `\section` only has one mandatory argument by default.

Comment: remove your `\section{References}`  and then define `\bibname` to be `References` instead of `Bibliography`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}
```

defines `\section` to discard two arguments so

```
\section{Something}
This is about something
```

will just typeset

> his is about something

as `{Something}` and `T` will be discarded.

For the bibliography do not redefine the class sectioning commands, just use

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
```

so the heading uses **References** rather than **Bibliography**.

Comment: Thank you so much for that, that's exactly the problem I was having and this solves it. Is there a way to keep the section numbering with the 'References'? As it stands it shows the word with no numbering.

Comment: @NatRodLopes you can copy the definition of `\thebibliography` from `report.cls` and change it to use `\chapter` or `\section`?? rather than `\chapter*`

Comment: I eventually solved it with this not very elegant solution:
\section{\bibname}
\bibliographystyle{naturemag}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{}
\vspace{-1.3cm} %to account for the blank space that was left there by the lack of the title, that I set to be nothing
\bibliography{introrefs}

Do you think it will bring probems?